# SQL count and distinct query

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I'm trying to build up a query that would count and distinct at the same time. This is the raw data

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMbyG.png)

```
+--------+---------+
| IntID  | ErrorID |
+--------+---------+
| ins001 |    1    |
| ins001 |    1    |
| ins001 |    2    |
| ins002 |    3    |
| ins002 |    5    |
| ins002 |    5    |
| ins003 |    4    |
| ins003 |    1    |
| ins003 |    1    |
+--------+---------+
```

What im trying to accomplish is a count for each error id for each distinct instrument id, as shown below:

[What is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnBwP.png)

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| IntID  | ErrorID=001 | ErrorID=002 | ErrorID=003 | ErrorID=004 | ErrorID=005 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ins001 |      2      |      1      |      0      |      0      |      0      |
| ins002 |      0      |      0      |      1      |      0      |      2      |
| ins003 |      2      |      0      |      0      |      1      |      0      |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: That's a pivot. Not the prettiest thing and not always do-able. SQL Server?  What version? here's a few examples for sql server http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/pivot-examples-in-sql-server/

Comment: How many different error id's are there? Is it always 5 or could there be 100's?

Comment: Why does the display have to be across?  Its generally easier to change the orientation to across in the User Interface and have the database return the raw counted data... using a count(*) and group by for example.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you have a finite set of ErrorIDs that you know ahead of time.

```
    select IntID, [1] as [ErrorID=001], [2] as [ErrorID=002], [3] as [ErrorID=003], [4] as [ErrorID=004], [5] as [ErrorID=005]
    from
    (select IntID, ErrorID, 1 as cnt
        from #YourTable) as t
    pivot
    (
        count(cnt)
        for ErrorID in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
    ) as pvt
```

### Edit

As you requested, If you have a larger amount of Errors you can dynamically build the query. Coalesce helps to build the strings for any number of Errors. (RIGHT is only used to remove the first comma from the string)

```
    DECLARE @DisplayList    varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @SearchList     varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @sql            varchar(MAX)

    select @DisplayList = COALESCE(@DisplayList, '') + ',[' + cast(ErrorID as VARCHAR(100)) + '] as ' + ' [ErrorID=' + cast(ErrorID as VARCHAR(100)) + ']' from #YourErrorsTable
    select @SearchList = COALESCE(@SearchList, '') + ',[' + cast(ErrorID as VARCHAR(100)) + ']' from #YourErrorsTable

    set @sql = 'select IntID' + @DisplayList +'
        from
        (select IntID, ErrorID, 1 as cnt
            from #YourTable) as t
        pivot
        (
            count(cnt)
            for ErrorID in (' + RIGHT(@SearchList, LEN(@SearchList)-1) + ')
        ) as pvt'

    EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: That is good starting point. But I do have a quite large amount of Error ID's. Any idea of how to go by?. Thanks

Comment: Hi @HernandoSalas if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySql or PostgreSQL, you could use a `group by` instead of distinct.

```
select InstrumentID, ErrorID, count (*)
from table
group by InstrumentID, ErrorID
```

Comment: Group by won't make the data go across the row as his image shows he wants.

Comment: I know, but that's what I would recommend and then he can manipulate the data somewhere else or use this result to populate another table with the result

Comment: And would this be limited to MySQL and Postgres?

Comment: Not really, but I am sure that it will work for sure on these two since I use them on a daily basis

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small amount of Error ID's you could do the following.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f562/1)**

```
SELECT 
    Instrumentid
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ErrorID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ErrorID_001
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ErrorID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ErrorID_002
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ErrorID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ErrorID_003
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ErrorID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ErrorID_004
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ErrorID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ErrorID_005
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY instrumentid
```

Comment: That is good starting point. But I do have a quite large amount of Error ID's. Any idea of how to go by?. Thanks