# Creating a single row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores an id, a field identifier, and a value to go along with it in each row. The table looks something like

```
create table personInfo(
  personName varchar2(100),
  fieldName varchar2(100),
  fieldValue varchar2(100)
)
/
insert into personInfo values('Adam', 'Address', '123 Cool Street');
insert into personInfo values('Adam', 'Height', '6 foot 1 inch');
insert into personInfo values('Adam', 'Hair Color', 'Blonde');
insert into personInfo values('Bob', 'Address', '451 Fake Street');
insert into personInfo values('Bob', 'Car Model', '2016 Prius');
insert into personInfo values('Bob', 'Hair Color', 'Brown');
```

Now, if I know the field names that I want but I'd like to return it as a single row rather than a collection of rows how can I get those back? So in this case, I'd like the result

```
NAME    ADDRESS           HEIGHT            HAIR COLOR    CAR MODEL
___________________________________________________________________
Adam    123 Cool Street   6 foot 1 inch     Blonde        null
Bob     451 Fake Street   null              Brown         2016 Prius
```

Here's what I've got so far

```
with tab as
 (select personName, fieldName, fieldValue from personInfo where personName = 'Adam')
select *
  from (select (select fieldValue as address from tab where fieldName = 'Address') from dual) t1,
       (select (select fieldValue as height from tab where fieldName = 'Height') from dual),
       (select (select fieldValue as hairColor from tab where fieldName = 'Hair Color') from dual),
       (select (select fieldValue as carModel from tab where fieldName = 'Car Model') from dual);
```

But this returns just one row, and without the name either. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You should look into a `PIVOT`

Comment: Do you know at compile time the set of `fieldName` values that you want to reference?  Or would you like the result to have an additional column if someone inserted an eye color attribute for Adam?  The sort of data model you have here is very flexible but it is going to be slow and painful to query.

Comment: I know at compile time that I'm looking for those exact columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a pre-defined list of Field Names, then you can try this.

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT personName, Fieldname, fieldValue
        FROM personInfo) AS t
    pivot
    (
        MAX(t.fieldValue)
        FOR fieldname IN (ADDRESS, HEIGHT, [HAIR COLOR], [CAR MODEL])
    ) AS pvt
```

If this list is not pre-defined then you can try using Dynamic Sql to create your pivot. [Like This.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35662895/5986923)

Comment: In what version of Oracle does this work? With "as" before an alias for a table, and pivot column names not enclosed in single quotes? Did either of you TEST this?